# Wildcard SSL on Debian 7, Apache2 not working. (Rackspace Cloud Server)

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, debian-wheezy

I have been having some issues setting up my godaddy wildcard SSL cert on a new Debian 7 server running Apache 2. Thinking maybe I have missed something and hoping you can help me out. Here is what I have done so far:

- Turned on SSL mod for Apache: sudo a2enmod ssl sudo service apache2
  restart
- Made sure "Listen 443" was in /etc/apache2/ports.conf
- Generated my key using openssl: openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048
  -nodes -keyout yourdomain.key -out yourdomain.csr
- Setup godaddy SSL Cert and downloaded ssl files (gd_bundle.crt &
  mydomain.crt).
- Uploaded godaddy files to my server via ftp and copied them to
  somewhere more safe.
- Updated /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl with the following:

  SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/mydomain.csr

  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mydomain.key

  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mydomain.crt

  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/gd_bundle.crt
- And made sure it has: SSLEngine on
- And then restarted Apache: sudo service apache2 restart

When I access the domain via https:// I get this error in chrome:
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.

And nothing shows up in my apache error logs.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: How did you configure your virtual hosts? What's the URL you tried to access?

Comment: The virtual hosts were all done automatically by the system (I'm new to setting up linux servers but it seems like this is a fairly new feature - Debian 7? - from online resources I have read). URL is https://www.orderly.ca

Comment: Your server just disconnects without sending anything. Are you quite sure you enabled the default-ssl virtual host?

Comment: That could be the missing step.

Comment: Starting to lead in the right direction now. Added my default-ssl site via: sudo a2ensite default-ssl (totally missed this) and now apache2 is failing on restart. Error log shows: [Fri Jun 07 23:09:03 2013] [error] Init: Unable to read server certificate from file /etc/apache2/ssl/mydomain.csr

Comment: Well, now you have a different problem. :)

Comment: Wanted to point out that I fixed this error. Was pointing to the CSR file for some dumb reason instead of the CRT file for SSLCertificateFile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at a connection to your site in Wireshark, and the server immediately disconnected after my client began the SSL negotiation. This leads me to believe you don't actually have an SSL virtual host enabled.

Try enabling it:

```
a2ensite default-ssl
```

Be sure to reload Apache's configuration once you've done so:

```
service apache2 reload
```